# Chaining Promises with custom error types with Kovenant

Tags: kotlin, kovenant

I'm using Retrofit to access a REST API and I would like to use Kovenant's `then` function to chain several units of work. In other words, I want to feed the output of one API call as a parameter to another API call.

I've defined a custom error type that includes a property to contain API specific error codes defined as follows:

```
class ApiError(val statusCode: Int, val apiErrorCode: Int, val message: String)
```

If an error occurs during an API call, an instance of this class is created with the appropriate error codes.

According to Kovenant's documentation, I can create an instance of `Deferred<V, E>` to obtain a `Promise<V, E>`. I was hoping that I could supply `ApiError` for the generic parameter `E`. I didn't see any generic constraints in Kovenant's definition of `Deferred` that seem to require `E` to be an `Exception`.

That being said, when I attempt to chain two functions that return `Promise<V, ApiError>` using `then`, I receive a compiler error stating that the expected type for `then` is a `Promise<V, Exception>`.

Can I make Kovenant work with a custom error type and if not, is subclassing Exception to include the properties I need the correct solution for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the base definitions do not have generic bounds for `E` but almost all of the extension functions do indicate the `E` is of type `Exception`.  Viewing the source code in Kovenant [promises-api.kt](https://github.com/mplatvoet/kovenant/blob/develop/projects/core/src/main/kotlin/promises-api.kt) shows that it is clear that most things have this expectation.

You can simply change your error class to be a descendant of `Exception`:

```
class ApiError(val statusCode: Int, val apiErrorCode: Int, message: String) : Exception(message)
```

Then you can throw it to fail the `Promise` or use it to call fail on the  `Deferred`.